# Hide Menu Div Class based on Url in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, url, hide

i have created a folder name js in theme folder and added this file(hidemenu.js).

```
 function getElementsByClassName(classname, node)  {
        if(!node) node = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
        var a = [];
        var re = new RegExp('\\b' + classname + '\\b');
        var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
        for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
            if(re.test(els[i].className))a.push(els[i]);
        return a;
    }

    var link = window.location.pathname;
    var locations = ['/locations/'];
    if (locations.indexOf(link) >= 0) {

        var elements = new Array();
        elements = getElementsByClassName('fusion-main-menu');
        for(i in elements ){
            elements[i].style.display = "none";
        }

    }
```

Later Call this in theme footer.php

```
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/js/hidemenu.js"></script>
```

But in javascript i see hidden class for few seconds or like flashes. Can we hide in a better manner or what about same thing in jquery?

Comment: getElementByClass is wrong, thte correct one is getElementsByClassName which selects all elements with that class. So make sure you have only one element with that class.

Comment: Tried that also. But still no results

Comment: is this script at the very bottom of the page, before the closing body tag?

Comment: No its at top, Its between the header tag. I added in Theme header.php

Comment: Put it at the bottom before the closing body tag OR in the footer.php file.
The script has to be loaded after the html is loaded so it can find the element and hide it

Answer (score 0):

Now According to your reply you can solve that problem by doing this:

```
//get the current page url
$getCurrentPageUrl = current_page_url();
```

then go to header.php you can put if condition like this:

```
if($getCurrentPageUrl != 'putpageurl') {
  //not show navbar code
} else {
  //show navbar
}
```

Comment: Tried but it hides sub pages. Actually structure is dependent on location page. So Pages are like location/city/locality, If i hide location this hides other pages also. So Only way we can hide by url.

Comment: Could you please eloborate the condition for navbar.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could make the menu class dependent on the page slug, then define a re-usable CSS class to hide it.

In the page PHP:

```
<?php

global $post;

// start with just the standard fusion-main-menu class
$menu_classes = array( 'fusion-main-menu' );

// see if we are on the page you want to hide the menu on
if ( 'locations' === $post->post_name )
{
   // yes - so add the class which will hide the menu
   $menu_classes[] = 'hide-menu';
}

// turn the array of class names into a string
$classnm = implode(' ', $menu_classes); 
?>

<div class="<?php echo $classnm; ?>"> 

</div>
```

Then in your CSS file:

```
.fusion-main-menu.hide-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

That should work. Then no JavaScript required.

Comment: Don't know but its not working, May be because of Custom post types and categories.

Comment: It's hard to solve without sight of your code. Have you got the development site online somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this in WordPress would probably be to make a custom page template for this page with a custom header that loads on on that page where you want a different menu structure. If you still want to do it with css, I took a look at the site and added in the code inspector:

```
   body.page-id-139 div.fusion-main-menu {
       display: none;
   }
```

I see this: [screenshot](http://screenpresso.com/=LBNVc)

Comment: I have no idea of custom template. Well for CSS, Its hiding but hide parent pages as well: [link]http://hangoutflavours.com/locations/in/bangalore

Answer (score 0):

Here is my header.php code this is different in each theme so select your navbar div tag from console panel:

```
        <?php if($getCurrentPageUrl != 'http://localhost/demo1/') { ?>
            <div class="head-container">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="sixteen columns">
                        <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
                            <?php   
                                if (fruitful_is_social_header()) { 
                                    fruitful_get_socials_icon(); 
                                }    
                            ?>
                            <div data-originalstyle="<?php echo $logo_pos_class; ?>" class="header-hgroup <?php echo $logo_pos_class; ?>">  
                                <?php echo fruitful_get_logo(); ?>
                            </div>  

                            <div data-originalstyle="<?php echo $menu_pos_class; ?>" class="menu-wrapper <?php echo $menu_pos_class; ?>">
                                <?php fruitful_get_languages_list(); ?>
                                <?php fruitful_get_cart_button_html(); ?>

                                <nav role="navigation" class="site-navigation main-navigation">
                                    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
                                </nav><!-- .site-navigation .main-navigation -->
                            </div>
                        </header><!-- #masthead .site-header -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php global $smof_data, $woocommerce; ?>
<html class="<?php echo ( ! $smof_data['smooth_scrolling'] ) ? 'no-overflow-y' : ''; ?>" xmlns="http<?php echo (is_ssl())? 's' : ''; ?>://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>

    <?php if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) && ( false !== strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE' ) ) ) : ?>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <?php endif; ?>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

    <title><?php wp_title( '' ); ?></title>

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <?php $isiPad = (bool) strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],'iPad' ); ?>

    <?php if ( $smof_data['responsive'] && $isiPad && ! $smof_data['ipad_potrait'] ) : ?>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php if ( $smof_data['mobile_zoom'] ) : ?>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <?php else : ?>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $smof_data['favicon'] ) : ?>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $smof_data['favicon']; ?>" type="image/x-icon" />
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $smof_data['iphone_icon'] ) : ?>
        <!-- For iPhone -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="<?php echo $smof_data['iphone_icon']; ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $smof_data['iphone_icon_retina'] ) : ?>
        <!-- For iPhone 4 Retina display -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="<?php echo $smof_data['iphone_icon_retina']; ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $smof_data['ipad_icon'] ) : ?>
        <!-- For iPad -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="<?php echo $smof_data['ipad_icon']; ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ( $smof_data['ipad_icon_retina'] ) : ?>
        <!-- For iPad Retina display -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="<?php echo $smof_data['ipad_icon_retina']; ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

    <?php

    $object_id = get_queried_object_id();
    $c_pageID  = Avada::c_pageID();
    ?>

    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var imgs, i, w;
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName( 'img' );
    for( i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++ ) {
        w = imgs[i].getAttribute( 'width' );
        imgs[i].removeAttribute( 'width' );
        imgs[i].removeAttribute( 'height' );
    }
    });
    </script>

    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/js/excanvas.js"></script>

    <![endif]-->

    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // Combine inline styles for body tag
    jQuery('body').each( function() {
        var combined_styles = '<style type="text/css">';

        jQuery( this ).find( 'style' ).each( function() {
            combined_styles += jQuery(this).html();
            jQuery(this).remove();
        });

        combined_styles += '</style>';

        jQuery( this ).prepend( combined_styles );
    });
    });
    </script>

    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $is_ie_10 = eval("/*@cc_on!@*/false") && document.documentMode === 10;
        if ( $is_ie_10 ) {
            document.write('<style type="text/css">.fusion-imageframe,.imageframe-align-center{font-size: 0px; line-height: normal;}.fusion-button.button-pill,.fusion-button.button-pill:hover{filter: none;}.fusion-header-shadow:after, body.side-header-left .header-shadow#side-header:before, body.side-header-right .header-shadow#side-header:before{ display: none }.search input,.searchform input {padding-left:10px;} .avada-select-parent .select-arrow,.select-arrow{height:33px;<?php if($smof_data['form_bg_color']): ?>background-color:<?php echo $smof_data['form_bg_color']; ?>;<?php endif; ?>}.search input{padding-left:5px;}header .tagline{margin-top:3px;}.star-rating span:before {letter-spacing: 0;}.avada-select-parent .select-arrow,.gravity-select-parent .select-arrow,.wpcf7-select-parent .select-arrow,.select-arrow{background: #fff;}.star-rating{width: 5.2em;}.star-rating span:before {letter-spacing: 0.1em;}</style>');
        }

        var doc = document.documentElement;
        doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);
    </script>

    <?php echo $smof_data['google_analytics']; ?>

    <?php echo $smof_data['space_head']; ?>

</head>
<?php
$wrapper_class = '';


if ( is_page_template( 'blank.php' ) ) {
    $wrapper_class  = 'wrapper_blank';
}

if ( 'modern' == $smof_data['mobile_menu_design'] ) {
    $mobile_logo_pos = strtolower( $smof_data['logo_alignment'] );
    if ( 'center' == strtolower( $smof_data['logo_alignment'] ) ) {
        $mobile_logo_pos = 'left';
    }
}

?>
<body <?php body_class(); ?> data-spy="scroll">
    <?php $boxed_side_header_right = false; ?>
    <?php if ( ( ( 'Boxed' == $smof_data['layout'] && ( 'default' == get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_page_bg_layout', true ) || '' == get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_page_bg_layout', true ) ) ) || 'boxed' == get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_page_bg_layout', true ) ) && 'Top' != $smof_data['header_position'] ) : ?>
        <?php if ( $smof_data['slidingbar_widgets'] && ! is_page_template( 'blank.php' ) && ( 'Right' == $smof_data['header_position'] || 'Left' == $smof_data['header_position'] ) ) : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'slidingbar' ); ?>
            <?php $boxed_side_header_right = true; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div id="boxed-wrapper">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div id="wrapper" class="<?php echo $wrapper_class; ?>">
        <div id="home" style="position:relative;top:1px;"></div>
        <?php if ( $smof_data['slidingbar_widgets'] && ! is_page_template( 'blank.php' ) && ! $boxed_side_header_right ) : ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'slidingbar' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ( false !== strpos( $smof_data['footer_special_effects'], 'footer_sticky' ) ) : ?>
            <div class="above-footer-wrapper">
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php avada_header_template( 'Below' ); ?>
        <?php if ( 'Left' == $smof_data['header_position'] || 'Right' == $smof_data['header_position'] ) : ?>
            <?php avada_side_header(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div id="sliders-container">
            <?php
            if ( is_search() ) {
                $slider_page_id = '';
            } else {
                // Layer Slider
                $slider_page_id = '';
                if ( ! is_home() && ! is_front_page() && ! is_archive() && isset( $object_id ) ) {
                    $slider_page_id = $object_id;
                }
                if ( ! is_home() && is_front_page() && isset( $object_id ) ) {
                    $slider_page_id = $object_id;
                }
                if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) {
                    $slider_page_id = get_option( 'page_for_posts' );
                }
                if ( class_exists( 'WooCommerce' ) && is_shop() ) {
                    $slider_page_id = get_option( 'woocommerce_shop_page_id' );
                }
                avada_slider( $slider_page_id );
            } ?>
        </div>
        <?php if ( get_post_meta( $slider_page_id, 'pyre_fallback', true ) ) : ?>
            <div id="fallback-slide">
                <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta( $slider_page_id, 'pyre_fallback', true ); ?>" alt="" />
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php avada_header_template( 'Above' ); ?>

        <?php if ( has_action( 'avada_override_current_page_title_bar' ) ) : ?>
            <?php do_action( 'avada_override_current_page_title_bar', $c_pageID ); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php avada_current_page_title_bar( $c_pageID ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( is_page_template( 'contact.php' ) && $smof_data['recaptcha_public'] && $smof_data['recaptcha_private'] ) : ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">var RecaptchaOptions = { theme : '<?php echo $smof_data['recaptcha_color_scheme']; ?>' };</script>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( is_page_template( 'contact.php' ) && $smof_data['gmap_address'] && ! $smof_data['status_gmap'] ) : ?>
            <?php
            $map_popup             = ( ! $smof_data['map_popup'] )        ? 'yes' : 'no';
            $map_scrollwheel       = ( ! $smof_data['map_scrollwheel'] )  ? 'yes' : 'no';
            $map_scale             = ( ! $smof_data['map_scale'] )        ? 'yes' : 'no';
            $map_zoomcontrol       = ( ! $smof_data['map_zoomcontrol'] )  ? 'yes' : 'no';
            $address_pin           = ( ! $smof_data['map_pin'] )          ? 'yes' : 'no';
            $address_pin_animation = ( $smof_data['gmap_pin_animation'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';

            echo do_shortcode( '[avada_map address="' . $smof_data['gmap_address'] . '" type="' . $smof_data['gmap_type'] . '" address_pin="' . $address_pin . '" animation="' .  $address_pin_animation . '" map_style="' . $smof_data['map_styling'] . '" overlay_color="' . $smof_data['map_overlay_color'] . '" infobox="' . $smof_data['map_infobox_styling'] . '" infobox_background_color="' . $smof_data['map_infobox_bg_color'] . '" infobox_text_color="' . $smof_data['map_infobox_text_color'] . '" infobox_content="' . htmlentities( $smof_data['map_infobox_content'] ) . '" icon="' . $smof_data['map_custom_marker_icon'] . '" width="' . $smof_data['gmap_width'] . '" height="' . $smof_data['gmap_height'] . '" zoom="' . $smof_data['map_zoom_level'] . '" scrollwheel="' . $map_scrollwheel . '" scale="' . $map_scale . '" zoom_pancontrol="' . $map_zoomcontrol . '" popup="' . $map_popup . '"][/avada_map]' );
            ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( is_page_template( 'contact-2.php' ) && $smof_data['gmap_address'] && ! $smof_data['status_gmap'] ) : ?>
            <?php
            $map_popup             = ( $smof_data['map_popup'] )          ? 'yes' : 'no';
            $map_scrollwheel       = ( ! $smof_data['map_scrollwheel'] )  ? 'yes' : 'no';
            $map_scale             = ( ! $smof_data['map_scale'] )        ? 'yes' : 'no';
            $map_zoomcontrol       = ( ! $smof_data['map_zoomcontrol'] )  ? 'yes' : 'no';
            $address_pin_animation = ( $smof_data['gmap_pin_animation'] ) ? 'yes' : 'no';

            echo do_shortcode( '[avada_map address="' . $smof_data['gmap_address'] . '" type="' . $smof_data['gmap_type'] . '" map_style="' . $smof_data['map_styling'] . '" animation="' .  $address_pin_animation . '" overlay_color="' . $smof_data['map_overlay_color'] . '" infobox="' . $smof_data['map_infobox_styling'] . '" infobox_background_color="' . $smof_data['map_infobox_bg_color'] . '" infobox_text_color="' . $smof_data['map_infobox_text_color'] . '" infobox_content="' . $smof_data['map_infobox_content'] . '" icon="' . $smof_data['map_custom_marker_icon'] . '" width="' . $smof_data['gmap_width'] . '" height="' . $smof_data['gmap_height'] . '" zoom="' . $smof_data['map_zoom_level'] . '" scrollwheel="' . $map_scrollwheel . '" scale="' . $map_scale . '" zoom_pancontrol="' . $map_zoomcontrol . '" popup="' . $map_popup . '"][/avada_map]' );
            ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
        $main_css      = '';
        $row_css       = '';
        $main_class    = '';
        $page_template = '';

        if ( function_exists( is_woocommerce() ) && is_woocommerce() ) {
            $custom_fields = get_post_custom_values( '_wp_page_template', $c_pageID );
            $page_template = ( is_array( $custom_fields ) && ! empty( $custom_fields ) ) ? $custom_fields[0] : '';
        }

        if ( is_page_template( '100-width.php' ) || is_page_template( 'blank.php' ) || ( '1' == fusion_get_option( 'portfolio_width_100', 'portfolio_width_100', $c_pageID ) || 'yes' == fusion_get_option( 'portfolio_width_100', 'portfolio_width_100', $c_pageID ) && 'avada_portfolio' == get_post_type( $c_pageID ) ) || ( avada_is_portfolio_template() && 'yes' == get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_portfolio_width_100', true ) ) || '100-width.php' == $page_template ) {
            $main_css = 'padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;';
            if ( $smof_data['hundredp_padding'] && ! get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_hundredp_padding', true ) ) {
                $main_css = 'padding-left:' . $smof_data['hundredp_padding'] . ';padding-right:' . $smof_data['hundredp_padding'];
            }
            if ( get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_hundredp_padding', true ) ) {
                $main_css = 'padding-left:' . get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_hundredp_padding', true ) . ';padding-right:' . get_post_meta( $c_pageID, 'pyre_hundredp_padding', true );
            }
            $row_css    = 'max-width:100%;';
            $main_class = 'width-100';
        }
        do_action( 'avada_before_main' );
        ?>
        <div id="main" class="clearfix <?php echo $main_class; ?>" style="<?php echo $main_css; ?>">




            <div class="fusion-row" style="<?php echo $row_css; ?>">
```